# Transitioning from Electrical Engineering to Astronomy/Physics

Tags: masters, physics, engineering, electrical-engineering

I have a Master's Degree in Electrical Engineering(Fresh Graduate with emphasis on Electronics/RF-Microwaves). I'm thinking Engineering is not for me and want to pursue Astronomy/Physics.

1. How hard is it to do so?
2. What ways I can transition?
3. How can I be sure that the fascination with the subject is a genuine interest?

Thank you

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: Note that a duplicate question still exists at Astronomy. It is probably best to delete one of them.

Comment: I'm currently in the United States (where I got my degree). But for the studies, I'm open to relocation to UK/ Europe too.

Answer (score 2):

The gap from electrical engineering to astronomy or even physics is big for a PhD. The other way around it's easier as physicists anyway specialize after master in a distinct topic, while electrical engineering is already quite specialized. Astrophysics is a field of physics that needs a thorough background in most of the physical theories apart from condensed matter physics. You would have to catch up a quite huge background. Only option I see is to dive into a very specialized PhD topic like, e.g. pulsar radiation or solar physics and trying to do simulations/data analysis on such systems. Other topics will need a lot of self-teaching and I'm not sure, even if you would be willing to spend this time, if supervisors or professors would like to offer you this time with alternative candidates. And many physics students want to get tenure in astrophysics, the competition is much higher in this field than in big fields like condensed matter physics.

I would rather suggest to you to look into topics and fields of condensed matter physics like spintronics, quantum sensing, quantum computing. Electrical engineers sometimes will have here an advantage over candidate with a master in physics concerning a distinct topic/task like circuitry development for superconducting quantum computers or quantum sensors.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a transition within the US is probably going to be easier than moving to the UK/EU. The reason is that doctoral programs have fewer requirements for entry. With your EE background you already should have a fairly good grounding in basic physics and mathematics. You may also have some basic research skills from your MS degree. If other things are equal (grades, letters, ...) you should be able to gain entry, but will likely require some advanced coursework as part of the doctoral program. This is pretty normal in the US.

I'm not an expert on European standards, but have the impression that they want students to be farther along *in field* and with more research experience. Of course you will only know for sure if you apply. I suggest that you apply to a variety of places that meet your needs.

I suspect, also, that there are more job opportunities in your current field, both in academia and industry, which might factor in to your decision making.